# Aggrid params sortModel undefined

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Hi i am trying to generalize my data source for multiple tables.
I am using datasource below and to do what i want i expect aggrid to pass sortModel as `params: IGetRowsParams` but aggrid doesnt update sort model. If i get sortModel directly from api i get correct sort model. I am using infinite row model.

```js
function createDatasource() {
  return {
    rowCount: null,
    getRows: (params: IGetRowsParams) => {
      const sortModel = this.gridOptions.api.getSortModel();
      const paramsSortModel = params.sortModel 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: sort model is passed whenever sort is clicked on the column or you are asking for more rows and atleast one the column has sort applied.

Comment: @sandeepjoshi yes i would expect that to happen but it doesnt happen i get null for params.sortModel i will try and make repro example

Answer (score 0):

If this is still an issue, you can get the SortModel like this :

```
getRows: function(params) {
        let sortModels = params.sortModel;
}
```

the gridApi you are trying to use might be outdated in its context.
the `params.sortModel` is an array of objects in this format :

```
{ 
   colId:"theColumnId",
   sort: "asc or desc"
}
```